# Como o .populate busca os dados

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou com uma dúvida sobre performance utilizando o mongoose.

Suponha os seguintes modelos:

```
const Disciplina = new Schema({
  titulo: {
    type: String,
  }
})

const Assunto = new Schema({
  disciplina: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Disciplina',
  }
})
```

Qual a melhor maneira de buscar os assuntos e os títulos das disciplinas de cada assunto?

1.

```
  Assunto.find({}).populate('disciplina')
```

2. 

```
  const assuntos = Assunto.find({})
  const disciplinasIds = assuntos.map(it => it.disciplina)

  const disciplinas = Disciplina
                        .find({ _id: {$in: disciplinasIds}})
```

e depois inserir a disciplina manualmente no meu retorno

---

É óbvio que a primeira maneira é mais simples e clean, mas minha dúvida é com relação a performance do `.populate`. Se eu tiver dois "Assuntos" com o mesmo id de disciplina, vão ser feitos dois `finds`? Como funciona isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma pesquisada maior, utilizei a flag `debug` do mongoose e vi que ele faz basicamente o caso 2. por debaixo dos panos.

Então é melhor usar o populate